# next/image does not load images from external URL after deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I use the Next.js `Image` component for image optimization. It works great on dev but it doesn't load images from external URLs in production.

What can I do?

Comment: I dropped nextjs Image compoenent, using img, its simple even though not optimized.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

[You need to set the configuration in the next.config.js file first.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#configuration)

***For Example:***

on **next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ['images.unsplash.com'],
    },
}
```

on **pages/your_page_file.tsx**

```
<Image
    alt="The guitarist in the concert."
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464375117522-1311d6a5b81f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80"
    width={2250}
    height={1390}
    layout="responsive"
/>
```

For versions above 12.3.0 this is the accepted approach:

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: 'assets.example.com',
                port: '',
                pathname: '/account123/**',
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Refer https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: just make sure to restart your terminal for the change to take effect!

Comment: Newer version of NextJS allow a more specific conf using `remotePatterns`.
See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

(`domains` key is still a working solution)

Comment: What if users wanna show many url from internet? Add 1000 domains?>?

Comment: @NicholasJela Maybe the edited version by CromulentCoder is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to display any images in nextjs app from accross the internet; here is my next config:

```
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    i18n,
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles')],
        prependData: `@import "variables.scss";`,
    },
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: 'https',
                hostname: '**',
                port: '',
                pathname: '**',
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Comment: You should mention this config.js is not work on production....

Comment: how did it worked for me ?

Answer (score 7):

Add and declare your domain in your next config, `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        domains: ["yourDomain.com"],
        formats: ["image/webp"],
    },
};
```

The configuration file, `next.config.js`, should be in the root of your project.

And lastly, restart project even in dev mode.

Answer (score 6):

For future references, I was having the same problem after deploying my next.js site to Netlify. Only later, reading my logs, I found

> Image domains set in next.config.js are ignored.
> Please set the env variable NEXT_IMAGE_ALLOWED_DOMAINS to "cdn.sanity.io" instead

So this is probably something to note. In the meanwhile before I saw it, I plugged this next-sanity-image plugin https://www.sanity.io/plugins/next-sanity-image to my page, which also bypassed the problem

Comment: Actually, It finally worked on the local build but still having the same issue on docker built on the server!

Comment: Hum, I didn't use Docker so I don't know if there's an extra config for this case. You used the env variable on netlify or the plugin?

Comment: I have a home server for nextjs where I deployed it with docker container. All env. variables (public/private) are working fine but I can't make this image trusted domain work. I even tried this docker container on my local machine and I got the same error over there too. Despite docker, they work fine when I execute my project with yarn start

Comment: @op_exchanger You have to add the variable on netlify itself. Here are the steps to do so - https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#declare-variables

Comment: @FarrokhRostamiKia Did you try ensuring you're copying the `next.config.js` to the Docker envionment? Spotted [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18412#issuecomment-751272319) with some useful suggestions in that thread

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're having trouble with next/image not loading external images after deployment. I faced a similar issue, and after some tweaking, here's the configuration that worked for me:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path')

const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**',
        port: '',
        pathname: '**',
      },
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Feel free to give this configuration a try, and let me know if it resolves your problem. If you have any other questions or run into further issues, I'm here to help!

Answer (score -5):

For me was just add blocker extension.