# How to set up Next image loader url correctly for external url

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host my first app on firebase and i am experiencing some issues with the image loader on next.config file.
initial config is as below

```
module.exports = {
images: {
domains: ['assets.coingecko.com'],
loader: 'imgix',
path: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/',
},
```

When i check the url on the deployed page the link direct to

```
https://assets.coingecko.com/https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579=&auto=format&fit=max&w=64
```

but the correct url be

```
https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579=&auto=format&fit=max&w=64.
```

i have tried to amend my config files to the following

```
module.exports = {
images: {
domains: ['assets.coingecko.com'],
loader: 'imgix',
path: '/',
},
```

or

```
module.exports = {
images: {
domains: ['assets.coingecko.com'],
loader: 'imgix',
path: '',
},
```

but when i do it and deploy the page again i receive errror 500  white page.
Can someone help a rookie please? i don't know what to do with it.

full next.config.js snippet

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
//const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
//const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');
//const withImages = require('next-images')


module.exports =  {
  images: {
    domains: ['assets.coingecko.com'],
      // loader: 'imgix',
      // path: '',
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  //...
}
```

server.js

```
const { https } = require('firebase-functions');
const { default: next } = require('next');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const server = next({
    dev: isDev,
    //location of .next generated after running -> yarn build
    conf: { distDir: '.next' },
    //images :{ domain :['assets.coingecko.com'],}
});

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();
exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return server.prepare()
        .then(() => {
            return nextjsHandle(req, res)
        });
});
```

Comment: Put the full url in the src - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66148998/15304814.  Read that thread there are a few other things it could be.

Comment: @sean thanks i have read loads of documentation online so far but none of the solutions provided fixed my issue. It is really a nightmare to have these images render. I know where the issue is which the path but what i do with i don't get the expected url. Any help is welcome thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I manage to get around it @rawwater @SeanW.

Basically what needed to be done in my case to remove the loader and the path from the next config page as follows:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
//const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
//const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');
const withImages = require('next-images')


module.exports = withImages(  {
  
  images: {
    domains: ['assets.coingecko.com', 'mywebsite.whatever.com'],
      //  loader: 'imgix',
      //  path: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/',
  },

  reactStrictMode: true,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  //...
}
)
```

on the `server.js` uncomment images as follow:

```
const { https } = require('firebase-functions');
const { default: next } = require('next');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const server = next({
    dev: isDev,
    //location of .next generated after running -> yarn build
    conf: { distDir: '.next' },
    //images :{ domain :['assets.coingecko.com'],}
});

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();
exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return server.prepare()
        .then(() => {
            return nextjsHandle(req, res)
        });
});
```

Then add a custom loader to my image as follow on the component this is supposed to render them.

```
const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`
}

<Image
  loader={myLoader}
  className="mr-3"
  src={image}
  alt="crypto"
  height={30}
  width={30}
/>
```

And that's it.